# diameter of graph with taxicab metric

Tags: metric-spaces, recreational-mathematics

I was just asked the following amusing question. Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the taxicab metric (the taxicab distance between $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ is $|a-c|+|b-d|$). Given a finite set of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the taxicab distance between any two of them is at most $D$, is there a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which has taxicab distance at most $D/2$ from all of them?

Comment: Is the distance of the point we're looking for also measured in the taxicab metric?

Comment: Is the point in question also in the finite set?

Comment: Question edited to clarify. Yes, also taxicab metric, no the point doesn't have to be in the finite set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a fun solution.  First, note that this question is *equivalent* to the same question asked about the $ \mathcal{l}^\infty $ metric on $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ since $ (\mathbb{R}^2, \mathcal{l}^\infty) $ is isometric to $ (\mathbb{R}^2, \mathcal{l}^1) $ (the taxicab space).

In $ (\mathbb{R}^2, \mathcal{l}^\infty ) $ the argument is pretty easy to write down.  If $ S $ is your subset of $ \mathbb{R}^2 $, define: 
$$ a = \inf_{(x,y)\in S}{x}, \ \ b = \sup_{(x,y)\in S}{x},\ \ c = \inf_{(x,y)\in S}{y},\ \ d = \sup_{(x,y)\in S}{y} $$
and take your central point $ p = (\frac{a+b}{2}, \frac{c+d}{2}) $.

Comment: Very nice! [filler]